# Why can't my user script close a window it opens?

Tags: javascript, browser, userscripts

I have this userscript:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var promoted, parent, link, tab, button;

function findParentDiv(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return null;
  }

  parent = element.parentElement;
  while (parent) {
    if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div' && parent.querySelector('a')) {
      return parent; // Found the parent div with an anchor tag
    }
    parent = parent.parentElement; // Move to the next parent element
  }

  return null; // Parent div not found
}


function findDownvoteButton(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return null;
  }

  parent = element.parentElement;
  while (parent) {
    if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') {
      button = parent.querySelector('button')
      if (button)
        if (button.aria_label == "through")
          return button;
    }
    parent = parent.parentElement; // Move to the next parent element
  }

  return null; // Parent div not found
}


for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if (spans[i].textContent == 'promoted') {
    promoted = spans[i];
    if (findParentDiv(promoted)){
      link = parent.querySelector('a');
      tab = window.open(link.href);
      setTimeout(function(){tab.close();}, 1000);
      if (button){
        button.click();
        button = null;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

My issue is that `tab.close()` in the for loop causes this exception: `VM1958:56  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'close')` although the window does in fact open and `link.href` holds the correct value.

I added the setTimeout thinking maybe there was a race condition. It didn't help, even when allowing enough time for the window to completely load.

Strangely, running this in the console after the script produces no error and has the desired effect:

```
  tab = window.open(link.href);
  tab.close();
```

That works when ran manually after running the script but it will not close the window when the script runs. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Use [`GM_openInTab()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_openInTab), and its `.close()` property instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To address this issue, you can use closure or a separate function to maintain the context of each iteration of the loop.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var promoted, parent, link, tab, button;

function findParentDiv(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return null;
  }

  parent = element.parentElement;
  while (parent) {
    if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div' && parent.querySelector('a')) {
      return parent; // Found the parent div with an anchor tag
    }
    parent = parent.parentElement; // Move to the next parent element
  }

  return null; // Parent div not found
}

function findDownvoteButton(element) {
  if (!element) {
    return null;
  }

  parent = element.parentElement;
  while (parent) {
    if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div') {
      button = parent.querySelector('button');
      if (button && button.aria_label === "through") {
        return button;
      }
    }
    parent = parent.parentElement; // Move to the next parent element
  }

  return null; // Parent div not found
}

function openAndCloseWindow(url) {
  var newTab = window.open(url);
  setTimeout(function() {
    newTab.close();
  }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if (spans[i].textContent == 'promoted') {
    promoted = spans[i];
    if (findParentDiv(promoted)) {
      link = parent.querySelector('a');
      openAndCloseWindow(link.href);
      if (button) {
        button.click();
        button = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works fine but it does still throw the same error for some reason. Any idea what that's about? (Thank you for the quick answer by the way).

Comment: @KwisatzHaderach, Try passing that reference in settimeout callback function, Something like this. This will hold the tab reference, and will be accessible when settimeout is getting called.

setTimeout(function(newTab) {
    newTab.close();
  }, 1000);

Comment: Hi, thank you for your concern regarding making SOF a safe place. Now, addressing your concern about whether I am using AI-generated answers or not, please note that I only provide answers in areas where I have expertise. If I were using an AI tool, I would be able to answer every single question, wouldn't I? I'm not sure which tool you are using (possibly AI?), to come to this conclusion. Please consider taking this aspect into account as well, whether a person is bombarding answers outside their scope.

Comment: Dishonest acts of ChatGPT plagiarism can only harm your professional image. Native speakers can easily tell the difference between your own words and those of the AI because your own words sound off to us whereas its words do not. Please delete this.